# Combining OptionsPattern with Pattern Constraints

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I would like to define functions with named optional arguments and to restrict those arguments to expressions with specific heads. This is easy to do with unnamed optional arguments. For example:

```
succ1[n_Integer: 0] := n + 1

succ1[]
succ1[4]
succ1[a]
```

gives

```
1
5
succ1[a]
```

as the desired output. However, I can't figure out how to achieve the same with named arguments:

```
Options[succ2] = {n -> 0}
succ2[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[n] + 1

succ2[]
succ2[n -> 4]
succ2[n -> a]
```

The previous code gives `1 + a` as the output of `succ2[n -> a]`. What I would like is to restrict optional arguments to `n -> _Integer` (`Rule[n, _Integer]`) so that `n -> a` stays unevaluated. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options[succ2] = {n -> 0}
succ2[OptionsPattern[]] := 
   OptionValue[n] + 1 /; Head[OptionValue[n]] === Integer

succ2[]
succ2[n -> 4]
succ2[n -> a]
```

> 1
>
> 5
>
> succ2[n -> a]